# how to use find in populate (mongoose)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I want to match a string with employee ID, employee Name , project name

My Models : (employee)

```
const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    employeeID: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    departmentID: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Department', default: null },
    employeeName: { type: String, required: true },
    gender: { type: String, default: "", enum: ["Male", "Female"] },
    designation: { type: String, default: "" },
    email: { type: String, default: null },
    branchName: { type: String, default: "" },
    employeeType: { type: String, default: "" },
    jobStatus: { type: String, default: "" },
    joiningDate: { type: Date, default: "" },
    leavingDate: { type: Date, default: "" },
    comments: { type: String, default: "" },
    managerID: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Employee', default: null },
    region: { type: String, default: "" },
  }
);
```

(project)

```
const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    projectName: {type: String, required: true},
    tech: {type: String, required: true},
    startDate: {type: Date, required:true},
    endDate: {type: Date, required:true},
    customerID:{type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Customer'}
  }
);
```

(employee-Project)

```
const employeeProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    empID: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Employee'},
    projectID: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Project'},
    allocation: {type: [Number]},
    assignStartDate: {type: Date},
    assignEndDate: {type: Date},
  }
);
```

I'm running my query from employee-project table which is my main table.

What I wanna do is to match a string with with employeeID and employeeName(employee table) and also with projectName(project table).
What I'm doing right now (which is wrong)

```
async rpSearch(data): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const result = await MongooseEmployeeProject.find()
      .populate({
        path: 'empID',
        select: 'employeeID employeeName designation region comments resourceManager',
        match:{
          type:{data}
        }
      })
      .populate({
        path: 'projectID',
        select: 'projectName tech startDate endDate customerID'
        match:{
          type:{data}
      })
```

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

First, `path` must be the field name of the schema. you set `path` with "employeeID" but "empID" is correct as employeeProjectSchema's field name.

Second, you set `match` but there is no `type` field in your `employeeSchema` and `employeeProjectSchema` neither. so you have to remove `match`.

```js
async rpSearch(data): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const result = await MongooseEmployeeProject.find()
      .populate({
        path: 'empID',
        select: 'employeeID employeeName designation region comments resourceManager'
      })
      .populate({
        path: 'projectID',
        select: 'projectName tech startDate endDate customerID'
      })
```

Comment: made a mistake, it is like how you told